# Java OpenCV - org.opencv.core.Core rectangle() method missing

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv, import

I have openCV-3.0.0 alpha and I found a sample code on the openCV tutorials website. I used to same code and compiled it, but eclipse tells me that the `rectangle()` method in the `org.opencv.core.Core` class cannot be found. I checked the class myself and indeed could not find this method. Does anyone know in which class this method is now stored in? I found a similar problem with the `org.opencv.highgui.Highgui` class which was discontinued in the openCV-3.0.0 and replaced by `org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

it is found in `org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc` package, e.g.

```
Imgproc.rectangle(webcam_img, null, null, null);
```

Comment: ... along with all other drawing stuff, circle, putText, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there anywhere I can find documentation for this version of openCV?

Answer (score 7):

in OpenCV 3.0.0 you should change

`import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;` to `import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;` , `Highgui.imread()` to `imgcodecs.imread()` , `Core.rectangle()` to `imgproc.rectangle()` , `Highgui.imwrite()` to `imgcodecs.imwrite()`

take a look at this link
https://fossies.org/diffs/opencv/2.4.11_vs_3.0.0-rc1/samples/java/sbt/src/main/java/DetectFaceDemo.java-diff.html