# Core.rectangle returns can not resolve method error in openCv 3.0

Tags: java, opencv, javafx, opencv3.0

In OpenCv 3.0,I followed a face detection tutorial on this [page](http://opencv-java-tutorials.readthedocs.org/en/latest/08%20-%20Face%20Recognition%20and%20Tracking.html) but this line

```
Core.rectangle(frame, facesArray[i].tl(), facesArray[i].br(), new Scalar(0, 255, 0, 255), 3);
```

returns error

```
Error:(205, 21) java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   method rectangle(org.opencv.core.Mat,org.opencv.core.Point,org.opencv.core.Point,org.opencv.core.Scalar,int)
location: class org.opencv.core.Core
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a "Cannot find symbol" compilation error mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean)

Comment: all drawing functions were moved to Imgproc in 3.0

Comment: @JoanCharmant I don't see how the two questions resemble?

Comment: @berak Thanks, changing `Core` to `Imgproc` seems to be working fine.

Comment: @ColnsAbt: From the other question: "What can cause a cannot find symbol : The compiler looked in all of the places where the identifier should be defined, and it couldn't find the definition.".  Here the compiler is trying to find the method `rectangle` on the class `Core`, and tells you that it doesn't exist. So it must have been renamed, moved elsewhere, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java OpenCV - org.opencv.core.Core rectangle() method missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26845885/java-opencv-org-opencv-core-core-rectangle-method-missing)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

opencv is updated to 3.0 ,some functions are changed.
So change the function from `Core.rectangle` to `Imgproc.rectangle`

Answer (score 0):

if you still want to use the core.rectangle.. I suggest you use OpenCV 2.4.10. library. not much different from 3.0.0..